# How insert Google Trends embed graphs in Google blogger POST?

Tags: javascript, java, google-visualization, google-trends

I try insert this script in my post:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/3523_RC02/embed_loader.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">trends.embed.renderWidget("BR_cu_WHKtsooBAAB_QM_en", "fe_line_chart_be74b3cc-8b89-4365-b142-13e39</script>
```

But I don´t see anything.

I need see the chart in my post.

I need the post content to be updated dynamically as proposed by the Google Trends script.

Comment: i think its not full snippet